# Is it advisable to create thread for each client request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, wcf

Code:

```
class Controller
{
    Some Action Method()
    {
        ...
        ...
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            //WCF cal- wil execute for around 10 secs.
            var result = service.SubmitAndCreateApp(params);
            sessionModel.IsAppCreated = result; 
        }).Start();

        return jsonresult;
        }
}
```

Since my WCF call is taking too much time, I don't want to use thread pool and make it starve.

It is evident here that the thread is being created for each client request. How can I optimize this or any other alternative way to achieve this in .Net 4.0 (VS 2010)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Your server will get DDOS'ed completely. At the very least, request a thread from the thread pool rather than creating your own by hand. If the thread pool runs out, you'll be waiting for one to become available. The rest of the server will continue to be able to work. Of course, your mileage may vary based on many factors.

Comment: @ Jesse Is it advisable to use thread pool for long running process?

Comment: Thread pool threads are background threads which means they will not keep an application running after all foreground threads exit.  This is not likely to be a problem for you, however, as your WCF request timeout should not exceed the ASP.NET worker process' idle timeout.

Comment: Moho - your comment doesnt seems to be relevant to my question. right?

Comment: You asked if it is advisable to use thread pool for long running process.  The answer is technically no, but in the case of your "10 second long" process with respect to the application's foreground thread idle timeout, it is fine.

Answer (score 5):

To put it simply: no, don't do this.

That said, you can look at the Task Parallel Library (TPL) in ASP.Net, which can achieve exactly what you are trying to do.

Quick search yielded this posting, which I only glanced over but seems on-point:

http://vizagtechie.blogspot.com/2013/03/parallel-programming-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 1):

Each request already gets a thread, so by adding another thread manually, you're creating two threads per request, effectively having your server's ability to field requests. Now, I won't be as apocalyptic as others: on a beefy enough server not fielding thousands of requests per second or more, you'll probably still be okay. It's still bad design, though.

You didn't mention what version of C# you're using on but on 5.0+, you now have `async` which is how you'd typically handle this situation:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SomeActionWithLongRunningProcess()
{
    await LongRunningProcess();

    return View();
}
```

This will cause .NET to offload the request, freeing up the thread, until `LongRunningProcess()` completes.

Comment: Actually he *does* mention that he's using .NET 4.0/C# 4.0, not .NET 4.5/C# 5.0.

Comment: Your right. Sorry, I missed that. For 4.0, though, you can use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async to add support for aysnc/await, if you want to go that route. Personally, I'd recommend it, as doing proper async manually is hard to do *right*.

Comment: That still requires C# 5.0/VS 2012 though, which he doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can complete the call to `Some Action Method()` and return `jsonresult` prior to the completion of your WCF call to `service.SubmitAndCreateApp(params)` (for practical purposes, assume this will happen 100% of the time).  If you want that to happen, then your code is fine.  If you need the response from the service call in `sessionModel.IsAppCreated` for your JSON result, however, your code is very broken.

To fix this, you would need to block the action method's thread until the thread it created terminates.  This fact along with the fact that the underlying WCF communication channel will already create its own thread to await response from the WCF service call (a synchronous WCF call is really just an async call that blocks until the response is received) makes creating a new thread pointless.

Comment: @ Moho sessionModel.IsAppCreated is not needed in my response

Comment: Sounds like this should be a web api/service call and not a standard web page request.

Comment: in which case using TPL or `ThreadPool` is not advisable as this should run on a foreground thread